# OData filter by max value and field

Tags: odata

The Dataset contains records with following keys: userID, **period** and **points**.

Is it possible to query one record per `period` and by **max** `points`.

**Example scenario**

**Dataset**

```
[
 /* period: 2016-01-01 */
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-01', points: 100},
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-01', points: 200},
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-01', points: 300},

 /* period: 2016-01-02 */
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-02', points: 50},
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-02', points: 70},
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-02', points: 10},

 /* period: 2016-01-03 */
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-03', points: 80},
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-03', points: 20},
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-03', points: 0},
]
```

**Query results**:

These are the desired query results. **One record per each period** and **max points for that period**

```
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-02', points: 300},
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-03', points: 70},
 { userID: 1, period: '2016-01-04', points: 80},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the `$apply` query option defined in the [OData Extension for Data Aggregation Version 4.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0.html), assuming the entity set to be queried is named `PointHistory`:

```
GET PointHistory?$apply=groupby((period),topcount(1,points))
```

This will group the records by `period`, order the records in each group by `points` and then return the topmost record per group.