# Filter duplicates by field max value

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a problem with getting data. I'm trying to get all users with there max value (points). My question is just like [OData filter by max value and field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084141/odata-filter-by-max-value-and-field).

Code for my question is:

```
 $query = User::select('users.id','users.username','games.points', 
 'games.created_at')
            ->join('games', 'users.id', '=', 'games.user_id')
            ->whereBetween('games.created_at', [$start, $end]);
```

But the problem is when I want to remove duplicates and get max points for each user.

In the version where I don't need whereBetween I'm doing in this way:

```
 return User::select('users.id', 'users.username', 'games.points', 
                     'games.created_at')
            ->join('games', 'users.id', '=', 'games.user_id')
            ->whereRaw('(users.id, games.points) IN (SELECT user_id, MAX(points)                
                        FROM games GROUP BY user_id)')
            ->orderByDesc('points')
            ->get();
```

Thanks

Comment: So, what you want is the max number of points for each user's games?

Comment: @Lucas exactly but in the date range(whereBetween)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem with using unique method form eloquent.

```
Game::with('user')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
            ->orderByDesc('points')
            ->orderBy('created_at')
            ->limit($limit)
            ->get()
            ->unique('user_id')
            ->values();
```

Thanks a lot to Lucas for his time and his help.

Comment: Cool. I was about to post the same answer :)

Comment: @Lucas Funny thing is that my query is not working as well. I have 3 users in db (test purpose) and today 2 of that 3 users play game and user with id 4 play game twice also user with id 5 play game once. Query return me just user with id 5. Do you know how to debug this.

Comment: I've created a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nVhTcDHuEcC3ZWojZTwsgV/0) and it seems to work. Feel free to play with it

Comment: @Lucas I've update create table and insert data and just time span for where clause and please check my results. There is duplicate users with data. Do you have idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Lucas Here is updated [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nVhTcDHuEcC3ZWojZTwsgV/2)

Comment: Looking at your dbfiddle, you don't have duplicates. Actually, you retrieve 2 rows for user duka9444 (for example) **because** this user made 5 points on both game id 17 and 18 (which turns out to be the maximum number of points for user 5). Don't know if that's clear enough.

Comment: @Lucas Ok. I see, but how to prevent that to display only one value?

Comment: You could, for example, choose to discard (on PHP side) *duplicate* rows for a user as soon as you have found a game for this user. You may also do it on the SQL query but that seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply `GROUP BY` your query on `users.id` and `users.username`?

```sql
-- I let you translate the query into your framework
SELECT users.id, users.username, max(games.points) as points
FROM users, games
WHERE users.id = games.user_id
AND games.created_at BETWEEN $start AND $end
GROUP BY users.id, users.username
ORDER BY max(games.points) DESC
```

That way, you'll get the max of points per user (id and username).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Because I also need created_at field in select

Comment: I see. But in that case, can't you just add `->whereBetween('games.created_at', [$start, $end]);` after `->whereRaw`?

Comment: Yes, I can add that but I also need to select created_at because I need that information (date) in data from db.

Comment: Hmm I think I'm getting what you're trying to do. Give me a moment and I'll come up with an answer

Comment: I am resolve this problem. I will provide answer in a few minutes. Thanks a lot Lucas!

Comment: Cool, I'm curious to know the answer